# illustrator gradient slider lightens up in the middle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient, pantone

I have a simple two color gradient on an image.

I changed the colors to pantone colors to print the design. But now that I changed the colors, the gradient lightens up in the middle.

I would love an explanation why this happens or a way to prevent this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you *can't* blend a Spot color (Pantone) to another Spot color.

When you blend from spot to spot the **only** option Illustrator has is to use the Document Color Mode (CMYK/RGB) for the blending. That results in generally a "grey" tone. It's a bit more prominent in CMYK mode, but it's there in RGB mode as well.

For Spot to Spot gradients you need 2 gradients.....

```
Color A 100% @ 100% opacity -> Color A 100% @ 0% opacity

Color B 100 % @ 0% Opacity -> Color B 100% @ 100% opacity
```

Then you stack them on top of one another, either via multiple fills in the **Appearance Panel** or by using multiple objects. And lastly, set the top object's fill to **overprint** in the **Attributes Panel**.

[image]

Prior to AI having the ability to use opacity on gradients, the gradients were merely created with 100% color to 0% color, then one fill was set to overprint. That still works as well. It won't *look* correct on screen (especially if you fail to turn on Overprint Preview), but it looks correct off press. Using opacity simply provides a slightly better on-screen preview.